# UI appears white when i use listview

Tags: flutter, listview

I am making my homepage UI and when i use ListView to make it scrollable i just get a white screen and the app bar. What i should erase or add to the code to make it work? .Before ListView i had a Stack .I aslo use a scrollcontroller added in the StatefulWidget. This is the code that i am using for the UI :

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  ScrollController scrollController;
  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}
class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Tariffo',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'SignPainter',
                      fontSize: 45)),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                  bottom: Radius.circular(30),
                ),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.center_focus_weak),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    String scaning = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
                    setState(() {
                      qrResult = scaning;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.perm_identity,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StoryProfile()),
                      );
                    }),
              ],
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false),
          body: ListView(
              controller: widget.scrollController,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                SearchBar<Post>(
                  searchBarPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 10,
                  ),
                  headerPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  listPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  onSearch: _getALlPosts,
                  searchBarController: _searchBarController,
                  placeHolder: Text(""),
                  cancellationWidget: Text("Cancel"),
                  emptyWidget: Text("empty"),
                  indexedScaledTileBuilder: (int index) =>
                      ScaledTile.count(1, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
                  onCancelled: () {
                    print("Cancelled triggered");
                  },
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  onItemFound: (Post post, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(post.title),
                        isThreeLine: true,
                        subtitle: Text(post.body),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Detail()));
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                HelloText(),
    
                // CarouselDemoState(),
                CategoriesScroller(),
                TopText(),
                //Appbar()
                BarDetail()
                //AppBarW()
              ]),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to constraint your `SearchBar` either by wrapping the other widgets with some `Flex` widget such as `Flexible` or `Expanded` or by giving explicit constraints to your `SearchBar`

```
SizedBox(
   height: 100.0
   child: SearchBar<Post>(
   ...
  )
)
```

Comment: and how i can make the bottom bar navigation to remain stack ( BarDetail() in the code)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your ListView into a Container Widget and give it height and width, I recommend you to use MediaQuery to set width and height for the Container.

```
body: SafeArea(child: Container( height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, 
child: ListView(
//.... your complete listview widget ..

) )
```